# Multi-language menu's / menu-items setup

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I might not understand Drupal 8 and the different Multilingual approach completely, but I'm bumping into all sorts of issues.

What I simply want, is a single Menu , containing links from 2 different languages.

To make this happen :

- I enabled the Language module, and set-up 1 additional language. Install was done in NL, and I added FR
- I enabled the Content Translation module
- I checked both 'Content' & 'Menu Link' under, so that I can translate both the Node & the menu title ( admin/config/regional/content-language )
- Set the language of the Main Menu to '- Not applicable'. I'm not sure if this is right, but the menu would contain links from 2 languages, so I thought this was best option ( admin/structure/menu/manage/main )

Issue #1 :

When I create a NL node & enable menu-link, all is fine on /nl , but on /fr the menu-link still pops up. 
This seems weird, as I have no translation or menu-link for FR.

Issue #2 :

When I click 'Translate' on the NL node, I get the FR edit form. I type my content, and I change the menu link title ( the field is visible & pre-filled with the NL menu link title ).
I now have both a NL & FR version of my node, but my original NL menu link changed with it.
I would assume that automatically , a FR version of my menu link would be created.
However, that's not the case. I have to manually go to Structure > Menus and click 'translate' on my NL menu link

Am I setting up the wrong way ?
Should I go for a separate NL/FR menu ?
Will I have to manually add functionality, to create a menu-item on the fly when I translate a node ?

Has someone done something similar and experienced the same issues? And perhaps have any solutions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to translate the menu items in the node form:

> Unfortunately the node form's menu widget was not made ready for menu
>   item translations (yet), so if you provide the French menu item title
>   there, it will be updated in the original item and not going to create
>   a translation. Until that is fixed, use the menu item translation
>   process as with the contact menu item.

[Drupal 8 multilingual tidbits 20: combination use cases with content and menus](http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2015-nov-18/drupal-8-multilingual-tidbits-20-combination-use-cases-content-and-menus)

The solution presented by Gábor Hojtsy in the link is to translate the menu in the menu management or use different menus for every language.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I didn't know that, but it seems the tidbit was raised after I asked the question.
However, I find translation it in the menu cumbersome, and when using different menu's, it doesn't automatically switch to the FR menu when on the FR node, but maybe I can pre-select it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is working now. If you go to /admin/config/regional/content-language and choose "Custom Menu Link" (and then select it again below when it appears), it seems to work.

Comment: Indeed, this works like a charm now.